# Google API find nearest postal code

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google has release new map API. I was just wondering if it is possible at all to find the nearest first three or five postal code according to user current location by using google javascript API.

Regards

Comment: What country are you asking about?  Or is this world wide?

Comment: Well most preferably Australia bit worldwide would be just fine too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is feasible with Google Maps API, but **Geonames** has a good API for postal codes.

All their webservices can be found here: http://www.geonames.org/export/JSON-webservices.html

You can create a free account that allows for 30'000 credits daily per application and 2000 credits hourly. Details about credits can be found here: http://www.geonames.org/export/credits.html

Check this example for a *reverse geocoding to find nearby postal codes* in Australia: http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodesJSON?lat=-37&lng=144&username=demo

Hope this helps!